# AWS Java SDK - Specify log group for Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Here is how I create my lambda:

```
final CreateFunctionRequest functionRequest = new CreateFunctionRequest();
request.withCode(code)
    .withRole(assumedRole)
    .withFunctionName(functionName);
final CreateFunctionResult functionResult = client.createFunction(functionRequest);
final String functionArn = result.getFunctionArn();
```

I want to create a log group and assign it to this. This has to be done before hand, otherwise AWS will automatically assign a log group. This is what I have so far:

```
final String logGroupName = // Create unique log name;
final CreateLogGroupRequest createRequest = new CreateLogGroupRequest(logGroupName);
final CreateLogGroupResult createResult = client.createLogGroup(createRequest);

final PutRetentionPolicyRequest retentionRequest = new PutRetentionPolicyRequest(logGroupName, 30);
final PutRetentionPolicyResult retentionResult = client.putRetentionPolicy(retentionRequest);

final PutResourcePolicyRequest resourceRequest = new PutResourcePolicyRequest();
// Don't know how to use this 
// I want my functionArn to have access
```

I can't understand how to use the resource policy (I think that's what I want?). I tried looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutResourcePolicy.html

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Policy NAme and Policy Group in PutResourcePolicyRequest.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/PutResourcePolicyRequest.html

```
PutResourcePolicyResult putResourcePolicy(PutResourcePolicyRequest putResourcePolicyRequest)
```

Pass the putreourcepolicyrequest object into putResourcePolicy and get the response from PutResourcePolicyResult()

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/PutResourcePolicyResult.html

Hope this helps you